# InstallShield installer current directory

Tags: installshield

How can I get the directory where the installer package is ran?

Thanks,
Abed.

Comment: InstallShield is a brand and represents more then one product and project type.  You need to be more specific to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

using the property `SOURCEDIR`.

Comment: could you be more specific with BOTH question and answer ?

Comment: Can you please specify which part is not so specific?

Comment: See e.g. Christopher's comment. What are you installing ? (How did you retrieve that info ?)